# Prevent image file from loading to canvas after file size warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, canvas

I am trying to prevent the image file selected from loading to the canvas if it is larger than the maximum allowed I have set. The logic checks the image and throws a warning, but still loads the image being checked. How can I prevent this from occurring? Also, I need to be able to clear the image previously loaded, if a new one is loaded and checked. A newly loaded image that is too large, is not checked for validity or have a warning thrown if its too big.

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("file"),
    renderButton = $("#renderButton"),
    submit = $(".submit"),
    imgly = new ImglyKit({
        container: "#container",
        ratio: 1 / 1
    });

// As soon as the user selects a file...
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {

  //CHECK FILE SIZE OF INPUT
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
  {
      //get the file size and file type from file input field
      var fsize = $('#file')[0].files[0].size;
      var ftype = $('#file')[0].files[0].type;
      var fname = $('#file')[0].files[0].name;

      if(fsize>54000) //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
      {
          $(".file-warning").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>The image: <b>" + fname +"</b> is <b>" + fsize/1000 + "KB</b> and too big!</p></div>");
          //alert("Type :"+ ftype +" | "+ fsize +" bites\n(File: "+fname+") Too big!");
      }
  }else{
      alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
  }
  //END FILE SIZE CHECK

    var file;

    var fileToBlob = event.target.files[0];
    var blob = new Blob([fileToBlob], {
        "type": fileToBlob.type
    });
    // do stuff with blob
    console.log(blob);
    // Find the selected file
    if (event.target.files) {
        file = event.target.files[0];
    } else {
        file = event.target.value;
    }

    // Use FileReader to turn the selected
    // file into a data url. ImglyKit needs
    // a data url or an image
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (file) {
        return function (e) {
            data = e.target.result;

            // Run ImglyKit with the selected file
            try {
                imgly.run(data);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.name == "NoSupportError") {
                    alert("Your browser does not support canvas.");
                } else if (e.name == "InvalidError") {
                    alert("The given file is not an image");
                }
            }
        };
    })(file);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When file size check is failed - you should save wrong state (by changing to Boolean variable) or simply break execution of function:

```
      if(fsize>54000) //do something if file size more than 1 mb (1048576)
      {
          $(".file-warning").html("<div class='alert alert-danger'><p>The image: <b>" + fname +"</b> is <b>" + fsize/1000 + "KB</b> and too big!</p></div>");
          //alert("Type :"+ ftype +" | "+ fsize +" bites\n(File: "+fname+") Too big!");
          isValidSize=false; // this variable should be created somewhere at the top. It will keep the state of file-picker.
          return; //this will stop any further actions;
      }
```

Comment: I slightly modified it with 
`//IF FILE SIZE WAS TOO BIG AND WARNING THROWN, BUT NEW CORRECT FILE SIZE LOADED, CLEAR WARNING
          else{
            if(isValidSize = true){
              $(".file-warning").hide();
            }
          }
      }else{
              alert("Please upgrade your browser, because your current browser lacks some new features we need!");
      }`

Comment: Sir, you have an error here: if(isValidSize = true).
You should not use assignment in if statement.

Comment: I switched it to 
    `else{
            if(fsize<154000){
              $(".file-warning").hide();
            }
          }`